# Why is my cron job not scheduled?

Tags: cron

I am trying to set up a cron job, by creating a file `/etc/cron.d/myjob`:

```
55 * * * * t echo hello > /tmp/cron.log  && cd /tmp/test/ && pwd > /tmp/cron.log
```

I tried to verify if the job is scheduled successfully, by using the redirections. I created the file at 21:50, and when 5 minutes later i.e. it is 21:55,  there is still no /tmp/cron.log created. I was wondering why?

I specify the user to be `t` for the job in `/etc/cron.d/myjob`. But whose is the cron job? I am not sure about it, so I tried the two commands below. Neither shows the job I created.

```
$ crontab -l
no crontab for t
$ sudo crontab -l
[sudo] password for t: 
no crontab for root
```

My /etc/crontab doesn't explicitly read from the files under /etc/cron.d/. See below. Can that be the reason that my cron job isn't running? Thanks.

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

---

Update:

Thanks to Jeff. change permission on `/etc/cron.d/myjob` to `rw-r--r--` solves the problem. 
Why does the original `rw-rw-r--` permission of my job file not work, but `rw-r--r--` is required? Do the files under `/etc/cron.d/` and `/etc/cron.daily/` must have the same permissions `rw-r--r--`?

Why does `/etc/crontab` not need to explicitly read the files under `/etc/cron.d/`?

Comment: what do you mean? I created /etc/cron.d/myjob manually

Comment: Which daemon are you running? I'm on Arch Linux using cronie, and `man 5 crontab` explicitly mentions /etc/cron.d/ being used as you describe, but I suspect some cron daemons don't do that.

Comment: How can I find it out?

Comment: In my case it was in the bottom left of `man 5 crontab`, but you could also look at which `*cron*` packages you have installed.

Comment: man 5 cron says  (Vixie Cron)

Comment: Sorry, no idea in that case :/

Comment: Permissions? https://debian-administration.org/article/687/So_your_cronjob_did_not_run (random google hit) indicates 0644 is expected.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. That is the solution. I am not sure why the original `rw-rw-r--` not work. I am not sure why `/etc/crontab` doesn't need to explicitly read the files under `/etc/cron.d/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Q1

> Why does the original rw-rw-r-- permission of my job file not work

From `man cron`:

> /etc/crontab and the files in /etc/cron.d must be owned by root, and must not be group- or other-writable.

So, the files inside `/etc/cron.d` should be:

```
chown root:root /etc/cron.d/*
chmod go-wx /etc/cron.d/*
chmod -x /etc/cron.d/*
```

## Q2

> Why does /etc/crontab not need to explicitly read the files under /etc/cron.d/?

No, that is not what it says. What `man 5 crontab` says is:

> /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
>     Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
>     command to install the new version when you edit this file
>     and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
>     that none of the other crontabs do.

What that means is that there is no need to run `crontab -e` to edit and install a new cron job. That the files under `/etc/cron.d/` are read and interpreted by **`cron`** as soon as edited. And the jobs defined within are executed as scheduled without calling the `crontab` executable.

## Warning

But you should also read from `man cron`:

> In general, the system administrator should not use /etc/cron.d/, but use the standard system crontab /etc/crontab.

That means to execute a `crontab -e` to create cron jobs.

Editing `/etc/crontab` (or `/etc/cron.d` files) directly is a bad idea in general and for new users specially. Get used to manage cron jobs with `crontab -e` and `crontab -l`, then, after some (long) time, you may try to understand what `/etc/crontab` does.

[Related](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html)

---

## edit

Since you are asking:

> Can crontab -e create cron jobs in /etc/cron.d/?

No, that is not what I meant. Cron jobs (for users) live in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` (in debian-like distros). That is where the command `crontab -e` edits them.

What usually got edited (before) in `/etc/crontab` are the `system` jobs, the jobs that installed packages (like anacron) use to schedule their own jobs. That is not a file that users should edit. In debian, there is a directory to add new jobs that avoids the problem of making mistakes in the edited file (`/etc/crontab`). That directory is `/etc/cron.d/`. But still, that is not a directory meant for users (even the administrator) to edit manually.

That is similar as asking why a user should not edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Of course that a user (as root) could execute `nano /etc/sudoers` and change the file. The system will not block root. But that is a "bad idea".

The manual for crontab is misleading in the sense that it was written to talk to developers (not users). It explains what a developer should do in those files.

#### Why

About: Why do you think that you need to add to `/etc/crontab` (or `/etc/cron.d`) ?

Files in those two places contain "lines", each line is a job.
Exactly the same is a line that is edited with `crontab -e`. Each line is a job to be executed by cron. The only difference is that in those two places, the job line contains an additional field for "user". But:

```
crontab -u user1 -e
```

Will also add new lines (jobs) (if the user running that command has the right privileges) that will be executed as "user1". The only (practical) difference is that a user could edit those jobs but not the ones inside `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d/`. That seems like a good idea IMO to avoid users from editing jobs of other users.

In short: to add jobs: Use `crontab -e`.

Comment: Thanks. why does "In general, the system administrator should not use /etc/cron.d/, but use the standard system crontab /etc/crontab" mean to "execute a crontab -e to create cron jobs"?  Can crontab -e create cron jobs in /etc/cron.d/?

Comment: Please read edited answer. @Tim